# xterm: Suppressing certain C0 and C1 control codes

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xterm

I really have no need for the majority of the C0 and C1 control codes.

For example the key-sequence <kbd>Alt+Shift+o</kbd> produces the C1 control code `ESC 0`.

This is useless to me and I would rather have that *bind* freed up for something else.


So is there a way to configure a way to suppress these keys sequences in my `.Xresources` file?

Or perhaps is another way that I haven't discovered?

Or for that matter is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

That <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>**o**</kbd> is seen by [**`xterm`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/) as a keypress event for <kbd>**o**</kbd> combined with modifiers.  The <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is a predefined modifier in X, for instance.

The [**`translations`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:translations) resource can be used to map various modifier/key combinations to a [***string***](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:string) which is sent to xterm.  You can make that string "any" sequence of characters (no modifiers!), and it happens before xterm sees keypress events.

In your .Xresources file, you'd override or modify key bindings by a multi-line setting starting with

```
*VT100*translations:      #override \n\
```

and the bindings on successive lines.  The [*Default Key Bindings*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings) section of the xterm manual has examples.